# Moving applications to SD card leaves some data behind

Tags: sd-card, internal-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should apps take up any internal storage when installed to SD?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14958/should-apps-take-up-any-internal-storage-when-installed-to-sd)

I have a Samsung Galaxy Ace. I have recently rooted my phone and now I can move the apps to the SD card, however it does not seem to work the way I expected. When I move the app to the sd card, some footprint of the app still remain on the internal memory. For example, recently I downloaded an app which took up 5MB of storage space. After moving it to the SD card, it still appears to use 3MB of space on my internal storage. Is it possible to move the app completely to the SD card?

Comment: The system doesn't move everything unfortunately -- the answer to the dupe explains.