# I moved some apps to SD, why haven't int/ext storage changed?

Tags: applications, internal-storage, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-s-5

The apps were all user-downloaded. Transfer size should have created generous internal storage "breathing room."

**Details:** 
Samsung Galaxy S5 Android 5.0 Via Android App Manager(AAM) reported completion of each move 64GB Samsung SD Card (presumably undamaged) Internal storage 90-95% capacity. Phone was restarted after all the moves. Cleared each cache before moving.

Referred to the following, but it is dated and from a different platform.

[Should apps take up any internal storage when installed to SD?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14958/should-apps-take-up-any-internal-storage-when-installed-to-sd?rq=1)

**Editorial:** Why, if so little storage is gained with a move, are SD cards so recommended as near-crucial in Android? After 6 months, my "Let the buyer beware" factor is growing with each swipe at each of Android's supposed benefits. Seems I need a PhD to embark on just about any change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound bad or anything but the above linked question still applies....
Really to save space you move things such as photos, videos, music and films to the SD card (This can be done via in app options normally such as within Google play music settings -> manage downloads -> internal / sdcard).

However some apps do store data on the SD card. One such example is a ringtone app. So when you download the ringtone its saved to the SD card. And some games save stuff to the SD card. So you may end up saving a bit of data here or there.

It really depends on the app as the APK's themselves can be quite large and are stored in the system memory rather than the SD card which also has limited permissions too which is also another reason as to why some apps won't move to the SD card.